# Object not rendering correctly from a distance

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am trying to render an image of a solar panel in the final render there will be multiple solar panels, some in the forground and others in the background.

I have noticed that as soon as I zoom out I get black lines/triangles going through the image. These lines appear on the 3D view as well as the blender rendered image.

I have tried loading in OBJ and FBX versions of the model, I have tried turning off the "use shader node to render the material" option in the material properties and I have also tried messing around with different lighting conditions. None of the options have worked. 
The texture applied for the solar panels is a simple jpeg file.

I have included 2 screen shots of the rendered image of the solar panel, one from close by and another form a distance.

Any information in this subject would be greatly appreciated,

Kind regards,

Thomas
[image: normal image]
[image: not correctly rendered image]

Answer (score 7):

You probably have faces that are very close together (or on top of each other).
Check your mesh for mistakes (e.g. select all in edit mode, then press <kbd>W</kbd> -> remove doubles).

Another thing to check is the scale of your model. If it is excessively large or small, this can cause numerical precision problems.
In such a case, scale your model, then apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Scale.

If the problem still persists, try to adjust the start and end clipping in the camera settings. The end clipping should be just behind the object (e.g. if the object is 10 Blender units away, you could set the end clipping value to 15 or so).
Note that this tip only applies to OpenGL and Blender Internal renders, not Cycles or other engines that don't use a Z-Buffer to calculate occlusion.

Comment: Hello B.Y.O.B, Thanks for your reply. Great problem solving, it does indeed have to do with the scaling. I down scaled the model and the problem was solved. One more question, if I down scale the model I wouldn't lose any resolution correct? I am working with high face count meshes constructed with photogrametry.  Greetings, Thomas

Comment: Since floating point numbers are discrete, most operations on them might "lose resolution". But I doubt that the precision loss is noticeable.